# Print the Report without showing the data

Tags: c#, printing, reporting

How can i print the Report without showing the data, that mean just paper output no screen output.

in my Master page i put a iframe:

```
  <iframe id="reportout" width="0" height="0" />
    </form>
```

and in my Ford.aspx:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     // Submit Button
     function OnSumbitButtonClick(s, e) {
        // e.processOnServer = false;
         var Temp = <%= TempId %> //Get value from Server
         //alert(Temp +'--'+ ASPxTextBox_NBR_COLIS.GetValue());
         document.getElementById('reportout').contentWindow.location = '../Print/BonEticket_Web.aspx?OdreID=' + Temp + '&CountOrdre=' +ASPxTextBox_NBR_COLIS.GetValue();
     }
    </script>

    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton_save" runat="server" Image-Url="~/images/Icon/Good-or-Tick-icon.png" Text="Enregistrer"  Width="110px" onclick="ASPxButton_save_Click"> 
                                 <ClientSideEvents Click ="OnSumbitButtonClick" />                   
                                                 </dx:ASPxButton>
```

and in m Ford.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void ASPxButton_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

          //Get new inserted ID from Database --> my SQL id is autoincrement
          TempId = oOrdre_BL.SaveUpdt_Ordre_BL(oPersOrdr, OrdreID);
           // Response.Redirect("../Print/BonEticket_Web.aspx?OdreID=" + TempId + "&CountOrdre=" + ASPxTextBox_NBR_COLIS.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl_err.Text = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null) { lbl_err.Text += "-->" +ex.InnerException.Message; }
        }
```

The problem here when i enable my javascript: `e.processOnServer = false;` it work, but i cannot do that because i need the calculated data from Server  `var Temp = <%= TempId %>`

Thanks you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer has two events onbeforeprint and onafterprint, they do what they say.
Here's a small tutorial on them: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/ie5print.shtml
However, if you are outside enterprise environment where everybody are using IE, you'll have to get creative.

An idea I can think of is show the to-print text in a popup window that prints itself and closes.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, i did the second choice : redirect to another aspx page, print it, and then use  Response.AppendHeader("REFRESH", "4;URL=../Ordres.aspx"); for automatic redirect again....but it is better when 1 choice work(without redirecting)